# Is it possible to create netns for a container before starting it?

Tags: docker, docker-network, linux-namespaces

I'm developing a network plug-in for Docker using docker/go-plugins-helpers and docker/libnetwork.

I've tried to create a netns and mount it in the sandboxkey path received in the Join() request but after return to request Docker doesn't use my netns but it unmount my netns, creates another one and remount it in sandoboxkey.

So, is it possible to create netns for a container before starting it?

Comment: Can you do that in the docker file?

Comment: What do you mean? Because my network driver should provide a different namespace for each container that uses it and I want the interfaces to live only in their namespaces.